# My First App tutorial "Unfortunately My First App has stopped."

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently looking through the Android Developer tutorials and am on the most basic of tutorials which is passing an intent from one activity to another and displaying the result.

Eclipse shows the app has having no errors and everything works fine (not functional) till I insert these lines of code:

```
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
```

I'm looking at the LogCat and did manage to resolve one error where i'd simply named something incorrectly but now i'm stumped again. Here is my current LogCat output:

```
10-09 18:09:03.882: D/Send Message Button(9652): Pressed
10-09 18:09:03.917: E/FragmentManager(9652): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{422e3888 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-09 18:09:03.917: E/FragmentManager(9652): Activity state:
10-09 18:09:03.917: D/FragmentManager(9652):   Local FragmentActivity 422d1598 State:
10-09 18:09:03.922: D/FragmentManager(9652):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
10-09 18:09:03.922: D/FragmentManager(9652):     mLoadersStarted=false
10-09 18:09:03.922: D/FragmentManager(9652):   Active Fragments in 422d1808:
10-09 18:09:03.922: D/FragmentManager(9652):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{422e3888 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-09 18:09:03.922: D/FragmentManager(9652):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null
10-09 18:09:03.922: D/FragmentManager(9652):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{422d1808 in DisplayMessageActivity{422d1598}}
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):       mActivity=com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity@422d1598
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):   Added Fragments:
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{422e3888 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):   FragmentManager misc state:
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):     mActivity=com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity@422d1598
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@422d1880
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):   View Hierarchy:
10-09 18:09:03.927: D/FragmentManager(9652):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{422d31a8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-09 18:09:03.932: D/FragmentManager(9652):       com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{422d37e8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020313 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout}
10-09 18:09:03.932: D/FragmentManager(9652):         android.widget.FrameLayout{422d43f8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
10-09 18:09:03.932: D/FragmentManager(9652):           android.widget.TextView{422e3b30 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-09 18:09:03.932: D/FragmentManager(9652):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{422d47f8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020314 android:id/action_bar_container}
10-09 18:09:03.932: D/FragmentManager(9652):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{422d4d00 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020315 android:id/action_bar}
10-09 18:09:03.932: D/FragmentManager(9652):             android.widget.LinearLayout{422d5270 VFE...C. ... 0,0-0,0}
10-09 18:09:03.932: D/FragmentManager(9652):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{422d6350 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-09 18:09:03.937: D/FragmentManager(9652):                 android.widget.ImageView{422d66e8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102025a android:id/up}
10-09 18:09:03.937: D/FragmentManager(9652):                 android.widget.ImageView{422d6a48 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home}
10-09 18:09:03.937: D/FragmentManager(9652):               android.widget.LinearLayout{422d7c40 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
10-09 18:09:03.937: D/FragmentManager(9652):                 android.widget.TextView{422d7f58 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020265 android:id/action_bar_title}
10-09 18:09:03.937: D/FragmentManager(9652):                 android.widget.TextView{422d8be0 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020266 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
10-09 18:09:03.937: D/FragmentManager(9652):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{422d9200 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020316 android:id/action_context_bar}
10-09 18:09:03.937: D/AndroidRuntime(9652): Shutting down VM
10-09 18:09:03.937: W/dalvikvm(9652): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f55ba8)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 9652
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{422e3888 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{422e3888 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:934)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    public void sendMessage(View view) {

        Log.d("Send Message Button", "Pressed");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Ran a clean and this is logcat now:

```
10-09 18:24:43.317: W/dalvikvm(9771): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f55ba8)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 9771
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4228bce8 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4228bce8 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:934)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
10-09 18:24:43.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9771):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Clean your project (Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu), and try running it again.

Comment: Done and same results. Logcat edit provided above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have replace the view R.layout.activity_display_message with text view. The layout R.layout.activity_display_message contains the container to put fragment into it.

The IllegalArgument is passed in your setContentView that is textView in your case so the container Id in you mainActivity is missing and your fragment is still attached to your activity thats why the exception occured.

Comment: Okay I think I've got what you're saying. I've got it working now but I didn't actually add any ID. I removed this snippet of code:

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
  }

and that seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: the Id is actually added in Your R.layout.activity_display_message xml file. You basically removed the fragment part that was using that Id .

Comment: Okay so "best practice" wise should that code remain in there and I should add the ID to the mainActivity or is it fine like this?

Comment: its only on your requirement,if you don't need the fragment or id to inflate it,removing it is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Though you have not provided xml. Check your xml file and look for **container** Because it says **No view found for container**. Try adding or replacing it with **frame layout**

```
10-09 18:09:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{422e3888 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your setContentView you have to set a layout you defined in /res/layout folder. There you can create your textView...
For example setContentView(R.layout.myFirstLayout);